# Appending a value to a global variable name calling it later

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I know how to append a string with a value passed by and show it like this:

```
function(value) {
   console.log("New " + value);
}
```

The thing is: I'm attempting to append a value to a global variable and then call it together like this:

```
function(value) {
   console.log(value + globalvariable);
}
```

But it's not working because it doesn't call the whole thing it just append the value as a string and then call the globalvariable alone.

How can I append this value to the globalvariable as a globalvariable name altogether, to be able to call it later?

I'm a self-taught person and i dunno if I'm doing this wrong?

Maybe there's another better way to proper do this that i will be awesomely grateful to see

I have already tried a bunch of things that doesn't seem to work

I apologize if i writed a duplicate

Comment: If you just want a string you can just `console.log(value + '' + globalvariable);` A little tricky but it does its job.

Comment: the thing is i need this to not be a string, i need to be able to call the content of the whole name altogether

Comment: Can you give an example of value and globalVariable and what the expected combined global variable should look like?

Comment: try ```globalvariable+=value```

Comment: value = "s";
globalVariable = 100;

I want to call the results of s100, as a globalvariablename

Comment: @Bosco if you think that my answer is the best solution for you, please accept it as [best answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309241)

Comment: yes i'm trying it thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested here [Dynamically create variable in javascript and assign value](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/dynamically-create-variable-in-javascript-and-assign-value/4792)

You can do this:

```js
var globalVar = 5;
function test(value) {window[value+''+globalVar] = 'newValue';}

test("myName");

console.log(myName5);
```

Comment: The thing was so simple i didn't even realize xD I just needed to put the globalVariable as a string too and create a variable like this: ````var test = value+"globalVariable";```` then i'm able to call it later as a test in everywere! You actually made this happen thank you anyway my friend!!! Will mark this answer as the solution, thanks for your time

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Anyway, just a suggestion... for your next question time try to explain better what do u want to achieve.  It was a little bit tricky to understand what did you want :)

Comment: I didn't even know how to explain it but will do my bests, thank you ^^

Comment: Actually the correct expresion is: ````var test = window[value+"globalVariable"];````